# Drop foreign key constraint in SQL Server without knowing the constraint name

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I have to write a script where in I need to drop a foreign key constraint, the problem is that I do not know the constraint name.

I know I could use `sp_help CHILD_TABLE_NAME` to find the name of the constraint and then run `ALTER TABLE CHILD_TABLE_NAME DROP CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME` to drop the foreign key constraint, But since I'm writing a script I need to do that programatically through SQL code.

Comment: If you don't know the name you can't drop it. Just like you can't drop a table if you don't know it's name. You'll have to use SQL to find out the name of the constraint, and then use that in a dynamic statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will give you a list of all the foreign key names on a given table. You should be able to iterate through them from there.

(Hint unless you want to drop them permanently it's better to disable them).

```
SELECT name AS FK_Name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyObjectName')
```